# Qual seria uma tradução adequada para "redact"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

"Redact", em inglês, de acordo com o dicionário Oxford significa:

> **redact something (from something)** to remove information from a document because you do not want the public to see it.
>
> Eg: All sensitive personal information has been redacted from the public documents.

Link: [Redact - Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/redact?q=redact)

Em outras palavras, "redact" significa remover dados confidenciais ou sensíveis de um texto para não ir a público, por questões de segurança.

Existe em português uma palavra ou um termo com poucas palavras que possa representar bem essa ideia? Qual?

Exemplo:

> The post was redacted.

Já dá a ideia de que as informações sigilosas foram removidas por questão de segurança. Como ficaria essa frase em português?

Comment: Talvez [rasurar](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/rasurar)?

Comment: "Toda a informação pessoa foi rasurada dos documentos públicos", "Informação pessoal rasurada"?

Comment: @JorgeB. mas foi rasurado por qual motivo?

Comment: Ah agora com a edição está mais claro. Deixa ver se me lembro de alguma coisa.

Comment: Quem 'redacta' ou exige que um documento seja 'redactado' alega normalmente razões de segurança, privacidade, segredo comercial, etc.. Mas estes motivos não fazem parte da definição de *redact* em nenhum dos dicionários que consultei.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[***Redact***](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/redact?q=redact) adquiriu recentemente o significado de eliminar informação de um documento para impedir que ela seja divulgada. As justificações para isto podem ser várias: questões de segurança nacional, proteção de segredos comerciais ou industriais, salvaguarda da privacidade de alguém, etc.

Em Portugal tem-se usado neste contexto ***expurgar*** com mais alguma coisa para clarificar a natureza do expurgo. O exemplo seguinte vem duma brochura de [Vieira de Almeida e Associados sobre *A Nova Lei da Concorrência* (2012.)](http://www.vda.pt/xms/files/Publicacoes/Nota_sobre_Nova_Lei_da_Concorrencia-Maio2012-.pdf)

> Qualquer pessoa que demonstre interesse legítimo no conhecimento de um processo
>   sancionatório pode consultá-lo e pedir que lhe seja fornecida cópia, extrato ou certidão do mesmo, ***expurgados da informação confidencial*** relativa a segredos de negócio.

Este [Acórdão do Tribunal Central Administrativo Sul (08443/12, CA 2º Juízo, 12-7-2012)](http://www.dgsi.pt/jtca.nsf/170589492546a7fb802575c3004c6d7d/a2a6e5965988319c80257a5c0034f787?OpenDocument) emprega ***expurgar*** ou derivados 27 vezes. Sendo um acórdão de tribunal, começa por listar em pormenor o que é que pode ser expurgado:

> “ 1. O [INFARMED](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infarmed) foi condenado por sentença, transitada em julgado, a facultar à Recorrida as informações por esta solicitadas e ainda não prestadas, após o eventual ***expurgo dos elementos relativos a segredos*** comerciais, industriais ou sobre a vida interna das empresas que eventualmente existam, devendo o ***expurgo*** ser devidamente fundamentado;
>   (...)
>   12. Tendo o INFARMED ***expurgado*** o documento em causa (...)
>   (...)
>   Por conseguinte, intitulando-se ***o documento expurgado*** “vantagem terapêutica” é fundado o receio da Recorrente (...)

No exemplo da pergunta, "the post was redacted," não se sabendo o tipo de informação que foi expurgada ou o motivo do expurgo, poderíamos dizer:

> O post foi expurgado de informação sigilosa.

Não me surpreende que não haja um verbo português com este significado específico de *redact*, pois este significado é recente. O meu *New Oxford Dictionary of English* de 1998, apesar das suas 2000 páginas a três colunas, diz apenas:

> ***redact*** (rare) edit (text) for publication.

[Esta resposta a uma pergunta sobre *redact* no ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4367/is-redact-an-acceptable-substitute-for-delete-or-omit/180883#180883) dá uma ideia da história de *redact*, citando um dicionário Oxford maior que o meu. Inicialmente *redact* significava apenas editar para publicação, não simplesmente expurgar partes consideradas confidenciais.

Em 2009 a palavra era ainda relativamente desconhecida no Reino Unido. Vejam este [artigo de uma jornalista do jornal britânico *The Daily Telegraph*.](http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/emmahartley/10100897/Redaction_the_meaning_of_that_word_in_full/)

Tal como o *redact*, de editar em geral, passou a ter um significado mais estreito, não me parece impossível que se possa vir a dizer simplesmente, *o documento foi expurgado*, entendendo-se sem mais explicação que alguma informação foi eliminada. Mas também não me chocaria aportuguesar *redact* para *redactar*.

Comment: Não dês ideias aos Brasileiros ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. lol. A única coisa é que passávamos a ter *redacção* , ato de *redactar*; e *redação*, ato de redigir. *Redact* e *redigir* vêm ambos do latim *redigere*.

Answer (score 5):

Se o objetivo foi retirar do texto informações sigilosas ou sensíveis, eu diria que o texto foi **censurado** ou que **passou pelo crivo da censura**.  A censura, no caso, pode ter sido qualquer técnico que recebeu orientação sobre o que retirar do texto original.

> - **censor** (substantivo)
>     funcionário público que se encarrega de examinar obras ou realizações de cunho artístico ou cultural, assim como os meios de comunicação de massa, com fins de censura, esp. política e moral. [**Google**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=censor+defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=BaVoVqyrLKWk8weqiYjICQ&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: Se me dissessem que o post foi censurado, eu entenderia que o post fora eliminado ou alterado por razões políticas, morais, mania do moderador, etc.. Entenderia também que a liberdade de expressão do autor do post estava a ser limitada [(ver censura no Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/censura). *Redact* não tem estas conotações: poderia ter sido simplesmente um nome apagado para proteger a privacidade e alguém. Poderia ter sido o autor do post a fazê-lo

Comment: Concordo com o Jacinto. Censura tem uma conotação completamente diferente de *redact*.

Comment: @Jacinto A pergunta define "redact" como "*remover dados confidenciais ou sensíveis de um texto para não ir a público, por questões de segurança.*"   Governantes de diversos países tem um gabinete especial para esse tipo de ação.  Foi a partir daí que escolhi a resposta que achei mais adequada.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que não temos em português uma única palavra para traduzir "redacted". Creio que devemos usar "suprimir" para "to redact", porém, indicando a razão. Por exemplo para "a redacted version of the document" eu traduziria para algo como "uma versão do documento com supressão de informações sigilosas e confidenciais". Fica longo, mas é o que temos... Pelo menos até começarmos a usar "redactar"/"redactado".

Answer (score 1):

No exemplo, traduziria por "removidas".

Comment: Mas apenas "removida" não dá a ideia de que foi "removido dados sigilosos por questão de segurança", pode ter sido removido por N fatores. Existiria uma maneira curta de passar essa ideia? Acho que com uma palavra não será possível, mas com poucas.

Comment: De fato, não passa a ideia de que a remoção foi de "dados sigilosos", por "questão de segurança". Por outro lado, _redact__ também não tem esse significado preciso em nenhum dos demais dicionários que consultei. A resposta do Jacinto é bem completa nesse aspecto. A sugestão que oferece ("expurgar") é raramente usada no Brasil, onde "remover" é mais comum.

Comment: *Remover* também é uma palavra mais comum em Portugal. Mas nós podemos 'expurgar' um documento (tirando alguma informação de lá), enquanto remover o documento seria o documento todo. Encontrei *expurgar* só em documentos técnicos. A palavra ainda não passou para a ribalta como aconteceu com *redact* no Reino Unido por causa do 'Hutton enquiry' (Vê artigo do Telegraph). Não consegui encontrar documentos equivalentes no Brasil.

Comment: @Jacinto, um contexto interessante para pesquisar o assunto é o da [Lei (brasileira) de Acesso à Informação](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2011-2014/2011/lei/l12527.htm). Acho provável que nela, ou em algum regulamento dela derivado, tenha havido a necessidade de transmitir a ideia de _redact_ aqui discutida.

Comment: Boa ideia. Eu nem sabia por onde procurar. Porque não fazes tu isso e escreves uma resposta como deve ser? Mesmo com o "removidas", a resposta ficaria melhor se mostrasses exemplos da sua aplicação em frases completas, nomeadamente numa tradução da frase-exemplo da pergunta.

Comment: toliveira concordo com o @Jacinto, se conseguir embasar a sua resposta será de muito bom proveito

Comment: Na verdade eu já tinha visto esse documento. A única coisa possivelmente relacionada que encontrei foi "reprodução parcial" de documentos classificados. Os advogados é que devem saber. Mesmo em inglês este sentido de *redact* surgiu nessa área, quando uma das partes em litígio é obrigada a ceder à outra documentos mas é autorizada a 'redactar' elementos sigilosos, como é o caso do INFARMED na minha resposta.